# How to use the same data provider for multiple tests?

Tags: jestjs

I want to reduce repeated data providers in tests:

```js
it.each([{left: 1, right: 2}, {left: 3, right: 4}], ('do something', () => /* test something */));

it.each([{left: 1, right: 2}, {left: 3, right: 4}], ('do another thing', () => /* test another thing */));
```

I can use a single array for multiple tests like that:

```js
const arr = [{left: 1, right: 2}, {left: 3, right: 4}];

it.each(arr, ('do something', () => /* test something */));

it.each(arr, ('do another thing', () => /* test another thing */));
```

Is there any other approach? I searched the documentation and I think I might have missed something

The perfect world for me is something close to what phpunit supports:

```php
class MyTest extends PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{
    /**
     * @dataProvider someDataProvider
     */
    public function testSomething($left, $right)
    {
        // Test something
    }

    /**
     * @dataProvider someDataProvider
     */
    public function testAnotherThing($left, $right)
    {
        // Test another thing
    }

    public function someDataProvider()
    {
        return [
            [1, 2],
            [3, 4],
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with what you're currently doing? Note Jest is an xSpec, rather than xUnit, test framework, so doesn't use classes to represent test suites.

Comment: To be fair, it's not really a problem, but more of a curiosity. Also, I don't even know the difference between xSpec and xUnit, maybe this is what I am missing!